# How to layout in android a complex layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to find a way to layout the following layout in Android:

[image]

Where as (4) is a background color, which should be centered on the bottom of the screen and be exactly 1/3 width of the screen. (1),(2),(3) are images, where (1) and (2) should be centered inside (4), and (3) should be centered on the right-top corner of (4).

Nothing works for me :(

How to use Android Layouts for this one?

EDIT:

I managed to create (1)+(2)+(4), but no luck with (3). Here is my code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutSaveShare_inner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@color/light_blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.43"
                android:src="@drawable/btn1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.43"
                android:src="@drawable/btn2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't place the views around the center of 3 in the xml layout.

Comment: I don't need that. (4) is centered in the screen and (3) should be placed according to (4) - in its' right-top corner

Comment: From your image it appears like 4's top-right corner is exactly in the center of 3. You don't want this?

Comment: Yeah, you can say it that way as well :) It's impossible?!

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. If you do want 3 to have it's center in 4's top-right corner then no, you can't do this in the layout, you'll need to measure and position 3 at runtime. If it doesn't need to be in the center then you could do it in the xml layout with an arbitrary value for the space. However if 3 has dynamic dimensions this could lead to some problems.

Comment: I know the dimensions of the elements, except (4) which is 1/3 width of the screen. I guess I'll have to position (3) in runtime. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following sudo code:

```
<someParentLayout>
<____Layout android:weight="33">
     <child items>
</_____Layout>
<RelativeLayout android:weight="67"
      android:background="blah">
      <TextView android:id="@+id/center_reference"
            android:layout_height/width="0dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
      <Images 2 & 3 to the left and right of "center_reference"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</someParentLayout>
```

The only part that you will need to experiment with is #3, I'm not too sure on that one.

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to do that part... the problem is (3) in my drawing

Comment: Hmm.. if you want it the way you describe it in text, wouldn't that place the right half of the image off the screen?

Comment: nope. (4) is centered in the screen and is only 1/3 of the screen - thus (3) is still inside the smartphone screen

Comment: Ohh, 1/3 width? height? both?